# Ubuntu : after upgrade, wire network is unstable

Tags: ubuntu, networking

Yesterday I have upgraded to Ubuntu 13.04. After I upgrade, I have a serious problem with network (I use wire network):  my network is unstable. After a short time using it, it often disconnects. It means the connected sign on taskbar is normal, but I can not browse the internet anymore.

The only solution that I have is unplug network, and plug again, and network runs smoothly again. I don't know why this happen and I google but no answer.

I'm using laptop with core i5, and network card is onboard.

Here is my network card info after I run command : `sudo lshw -C network`

```
*-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: d0:df:9a:e2:81:c7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.8.0-19-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 memory:c0500000-c050ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: c0
       serial: e8:9a:8f:b9:af:57
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.1-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.1.100 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:49 memory:c0400000-c043ffff ioport:2000(size=128)
```

And here is my laptop information:

```
System Information
        Manufacturer: TOSHIBA
        Product Name: Satellite L755
        Version: PSK1YL-006001
        Serial Number: 9B077988W
        UUID: 2690FBA0-D81A-11E0-9FD1-E89A8FB9AF57
        Wake-up Type: Power Switch
        SKU Number: PSK1YL-006001
        Family: Intel_Mobile
```

Please help me about this issue.

Comment: Please tell us your networking setup and what kind of network card you do have.

Comment: can you tell me how to do that. because i'm a newcommer to linux world. thanks :)

Comment: but, i meet this problem after upgrade to ubuntu 13.05. before that is normal. Before I use Ubuntu, I use Fedora and still meet this situation :(

Comment: I think what everyone is looking for is what type of hardware do you have? Try to be as specific as possible, model numbers, brand name, etc. Let's start with that, we'll need you to do some additional information collection in order to get to the root of the problem, so be prepared 8-).

Comment: @slm I have added a little information about my netword card.

Comment: What laptop model?

Comment: Are you using a fixed IP address or DHCP? How many other people are connected to the same wired network?

Comment: @schaiba I have added to my post.

Comment: @DeerHunter how to know those information ? I have met this problem after upgrade :(

Comment: I have a similar problem with wireless on Debian. I think it's a bug in NetworkManager because it goes away when I do` service network-manager restart` I haven't had the time to check if there's been such a bug report though. When the network is down, what happens if you run `pgrep dhclient`?

Comment: @JosephR. when network is down, I run `pgrep dhclient`, it appears two number : 8383 and 11254. I don't really understand the meaning of those number.

Comment: These are the process IDs of any process whose name matches the pattern `dhclient`. The same thing would happen with me when the connection was "wavering". It seems that every time the connection goes down and back up, it's because a new instance of `dhclient` (the program responsible for making DHCP requests) was started for some reason. In my case, I would get 4 to 5 processes, which shouldn't be the case as a DHCP lease usually lasts for a quite a while (at least that's the default configuration on most DHCP servers I've seen). Does `service network-manager restart` help?

Comment: By the way, how consistent/reproducible is this?

Comment: @JosephR. as you say, I have tested, when network is normal, just one process of dhclient, but when network is not running, always two processes of dhclient.

Comment: @JosephR. about `service network-manager restart`. I run this command two times. First time, it disconnect network but cannot start again (loading icon, and forever), but second time, it starts successfully. My problem maybe looks like as you.

Comment: @JosephR.: I know I am late in this game (experiencing this problem upgrading from Ubuntu 13.10 to 14.04). In my case the service-restart seems to solve the problem. Could you explain why the `service network-manager restart` solve the issue?

Comment: @tokosh Got me... It seems to be a bug and [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73886/ubuntu-after-upgrade-wire-network-is-unstable#comment107374_73886) remains the best explanation (symptom, really) that I can see. FWIW, I no longer have that problem (didn't see it on Debian Wheezy, don't see it on Jessie).

Comment: @JosephR. thanks. My colleague uses the same version of Ubuntu running on the exact same machine (however, he upgraded from 12.X) and he did not have this issue.